# Tailwind: How the order of stacked modifiers and atbitrary varians affects the style

Tags: tailwind-css

The official document of Tailwind CSS says:

> Arbitrary variants can be stacked with built-in modifiers or with each other, just like the rest of the modifiers in Tailwind:

In the process of researching this point, I noticed a peculiar phenomenon. Compare the following two classes.

- `hover:[&_p]:text-red-500`
- `[&_p]:hover:text-red-500`

I predicted that they would produce the same CSS declarations, but in fact they produced different fragments as follows:

```css
.hover\:\[\&_p\]\:text-red-500 p:hover {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.\[\&_p\]\:hover\:text-red-500:hover p {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

It seems to me that the former is correct and the latter incorrect. How should I interpret this phenomenon?

I have confirmed this phenomenon with Tailwind 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#ordering-stacked-modifiers):

> When stacking modifiers, they are applied from the inside-out, like nested function calls:
>
> ```js
> // These modifiers:
> 'dark:group-hover:focus:opacity-100'
>
> // ...are applied like this:
> dark(groupHover(focus('opacity-100')))
> ```
>
> For the most part this doesn’t actually matter, but there are a few
> situations where the order you use actually generates meaningfully different CSS.
>
> For example, if you have `darkMode` configured to `class`, combining the `dark` and `group-hover` modifiers generates a different result depending on the order you use:
>
> ```css
> /* dark:group-hover:opacity-100 */
> .dark .group:hover .dark\:group-hover\:opacity-100 {
>   opacity: 1;
> }
>
> /* group-hover:dark:opacity-100 */
> .group:hover .dark .group-hover\:dark\:opacity-100 {
>   opacity: 1;
> }
> ```